# Why Hibernate Criteria Queries and session.getMetadata() are deprecated?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

In latest relase of Hibernate `Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(entityClass)` and `session.getMetamodel()` methods are deprecated. Criteria API was the cleanest querying API, why is it deprecated? `getMeatamodel()` is also deprecated, so how can I  ManagedType or EmbeddableType from Hibernate session?

```
ManagedType<T> entityType = entityModel.managedType(entityClass);
java.util.Set<EmbeddableType<?>> embeddables = entityModel.getEmbeddables();
```

Comment: "This appendix covers the legacy Hibernate org.hibernate.Criteria API, which should be considered deprecated. New development should focus on the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery API. Eventually, Hibernate-specific criteria features will be ported as extensions to the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery."

The future is JPA criteria.